# Deleted entity is in list in related Entity, but I can't find it by repository

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have following code:

```
@Transactional
public void delete(String id) {
    PersonEntity personEntity = personRepository.findOne(id); 
    //has one address with ID = 10      
    personEntity.getAddresses().stream().forEach(address -> addressRepository.delete(address.getId())); 
    PersonEntity personEntity2 = personRepository.findOne(id); 
    // not empty - I can see that are existing one address with ID = 10 
    personEntity2.getAddresses();
    // ID = 10, but here is null
    addressRepository.findOne(10); 
}
```

Why I can see deleted entity in list of related entity, but when I use `findOne` with this `ID`, method returns `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how JPA works:

Within your `delete` you delete all addresses from a person. To be precise you delete the addresses out of the JPA managed context. That's why you get `null` when you call `addressRepository.findOne(10)` (even before the transaction gets committed) because those addresses don't exist in the JPA context andymore. When your transaction gets committed finally, the addresses will be erased from the database (not earlier).

As you don't erase the addresses from the persons list of addresses, they will still remain there (before and after the transaction gets committed), even if the referenced entities don't have a corresponding record on the database anymore.

To reflect the deletions on the database to your person again, you could call `entitymanager.refresh(personEntity)` if you already have a not close entity manager session after the transaction was commited, or just call `personEntity = personRepository.findOne(id)` again.

A more elegant solution was already suggested by @Vikram Singh. To get this working you additional need to map the realtion from person to addresse with orhapn removal = true `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true`)

Comment: I called `findOne` after I deleted addresses. `PersonEntity personEntity2 = personRepository.findOne(id); `

Comment: And address list is still not empty, so I don't know if your answer is correct

Comment: Where did you call `PersonEntity personEntity2 = personRepository.findOne(id)`. If inside the `delete` method, the addresses are still not removed from the database and the person is not modified within the JPA context (only referenced addresses are removed), so if the person would still have the addresses reference would be the expected behavior.

If called after the transaction was committed, it depends whether the entity manager session is closed. If not, try entitymanager.refresh(). If yes, open a new session and call `personRepository.findOne(id)` again.

Comment: In my question I described where.
Ok, so references in DB are deleted, but references in `List<Address>` in `Person` side are not refreshed, yes?

Comment: I'm afraid, if you need a person without addresses referenced within your `delete` method, the only way is to use `orphanRemoval=true` in your `@...ToMany` mapping and delete the addresses out of the list instead of deleting them via repository. The reason is: In the JPA context the person is not modified (only the addresses are). So you will always get a person with address references if queried for from database or JPA context.

Answer (score 0):

do not call delete method just remove entity from the list. jpa will take care of deleting after the transaction is completed.or you can do entityManager.flush() after removing.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I am not asking how to do this - I am asking why